# non-bootstrap datepicker directive angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I am using "angular material" http://material.angularjs.org where including bootstrap is not an option (at least for the project im working on).

I need to implement datepicker when someone clicks on the text. Angular material provides datepicker but it comes only with input as a required field. Is there a way to implement inline datepicker on any element on the page? Ideally directive would be great but maybe there is an independent (framework independent) datepicker as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found library called "pikaday-angular" https://github.com/nverba/pikaday-angular

Lightweight, independent with plenty of configurations (javascript date, momentjs). It can also be jQuery non-dependent if there is a need.

Seems working for me. Just need to play with some styles(css) and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the library

```
https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker


and working pen
here:

http://codepen.io/Nataraj32/pen/ONVMQm
```

Comment: This only works with input fields. My question asks if there is a datepicker which you can attach to any element on the page

Comment: dont you see my code pen i attached with a div... i am clicking on a div to open that pls check that

Comment: I cant make it work with ng-model, as soon as I add ng-model I cannot reuse it. Could you modify your code so that it works with ng-model (but without input field). Cheers